# REST Authentication With Spring And Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I want develop a RESTfull web service with authentication using Spring and Spring Security.
All my users will be stored in the DB with an encrypted password and role.
The session should be stored in the context until the session is timedout or logged out to allow consumption of other webservices.

If someone can help me would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I found something pretty clear here: http://www.networkedassets.com/configuring-spring-security-for-a-restful-web-services/

Comment: Also here another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733418/login-logout-in-rest-with-spring-3/14735345#14735345

Comment: Another good article: http://www.baeldung.com/2012/04/16/how-to-use-resttemplate-with-basic-authentication-in-spring-3-1/#resttemplate

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Jersey with Spring and its ContextSecurityFilter, I do not suggest to use spring security. If you make a good Authorization try to use @RolesAllowed method.