# How to disable static content handle in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733418/login-logout-in-rest-with-spring-3) link to configure security and spring-boot as base for other. But static resource handler provided by spring-boot is executed before security settings. So if I send POST request, static content handler respond me that method POST not supported. If I request GET method, static response handler catch it and try to find resourse. So any requests catched by static content handler and not go to security filters.

How can I disable static content filters/handlers provided by spring-boot?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot 2.4.0 or later, you can disable the static resource handling by setting `spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false` in your `application.properties` file. In earlier versions of Spring Boot, the property is `spring.resources.add-mappings`.

With that out of the way, are you sure that it will resolve your problem? Spring Security runs as a filter *before* the static resource handling and I doubt that disabling the resource handling will help. Perhaps it'll make it easier to identify the underlying problem, though.

Comment: spring.resources.add-mappings does not completely disable resource handling. It has the effect that no ResourceHandler is added automatically, but you can still add them manually by WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.addResourceHandlers.

Comment: On newer versions of spring, the property name is 'spring.web.resources.add-mappings'