# properties files are used in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

What is the use of these properties in `application.properties` file
and when do we use them?

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.sources.add-mappings=false
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

strg + f "spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found" => profit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to these resources

1. [disable the static resource handling in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496262/how-to-disable-static-content-handle-in-spring-boot)
2. [Spring Boot application-properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

you can use

```
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

for disabling the default handling of classpath/ JAR/ file system resources (like `css` or image files) in case you would like to restrict access to them and create your own mappings

and

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

if you wish an exception of type `NoHandlerFoundException` to be thrown in case no `handler` is found in processing a `request` (and maybe catch it and take same appropriate action).

Comment: You can disable the static resource handling by setting spring.resources.add-mappings=false in your application.properties.

With that out of the way, are you sure that it will resolve your problem? Spring Security runs as a filter before the static resource handling and I doubt that disabling the resource handling will help. Perhaps it'll make it easier to identify the underlying problem, though.