# How does form based authentication work in spring security?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-security, form-authentication

Say `post` request was send to some `/login` url, with valid `username` and `password` parameters.

What should be in response? Must it contains jsessionid or/and other information?

How spring security identifies current user? Does it uses `jsessionid` filtering or it "looks" at other information (custome header, cookies etc.)? By "`jsessionid` filtering" **I mean** (may be it is wrong) that when user logins successfully spring security save `jsessionid` to successful authentificated session list and save other information (like roles) into session object. Does it works like that or not?

It would be nice if somebody provide step by step **raw** http requests/responses with authentication, for example what `post` request should contain and what corresponding response contains. Also, what request to secured resource need to contain (some header, cookie, jsession or else)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276806/spring-security-testing-understanding-rest-authentication  . In this question, at bottom of main post, you can see how Spring-Security responds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to help you:

**First:** The response sets a cookie for that path,in my case my application is in `localhost:port/CambioClaveDist`, so when SpringSecurity authenticate my user, it creates a new JSESSIONID for that path:     `Set-Cookie:"JSESSIONID=96ABDF25EE278DD69DD1A0400702E416; Path=/CambioClaveDist"`

**Second:** Spring identifies an authenticated user with the JSESSIONID, yes.

**Third:** I have an http request/post example:
Authentication post:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/CambioClaveDist/j_spring_security_check
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:8080/CambioClaveDist/index.htm?logout=true
Connection: keep-alive

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 92

_csrf=fbd07004-cc30-4ef6-9bfb-a00ae8f8819f&username=user&password=pass&sSubmit=Enviar
```

Request to protected url:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/CambioClaveDist/main/index.htm

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:8080/CambioClaveDist/index.htm?logout=true
Cookie: JSESSIONID=96ABDF25EE278DD69DD1A0400702E416
Connection: keep-alive
```